# client server in android

Tags: android, client

I am new to the android .
In android in exact what application socket programming is used?,give example with digram if posible. which is client, which is serve?r

--
kiran

Answer (score 0):

Socket programming is the same everywhere.  One application might be if you are using your Android as a controller for an external system (perhaps a set-top box, etc).  You might set up the external system as the server and the Android system as the client.

Comment: Implementation examples discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2132241/android-open-socket-and-send-commands