# android open socket and send commands

Tags: java, android, sockets

Hay Guys, I'm new to Android but heres what i want to do.

I want to beable to open a connect to a server using a given IP and PORT, then send commands to the server and get data back.

Any ideas what i need to google to help on this? I know how to do it in PHP (using fputs, fgets, and fsockopen).

any help would be brill.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [java.net](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/package-summary.html) classes.  Below is a simple example using DatagramSockets:

```
String cmd("my command");
    try {
        InetSocketAddress address = new InetSocketAddress("10.1.1.1", 12350);
        DatagramPacket request = new DatagramPacket(cmd.getBytes(), cmd.length(), address);
        DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket();
        socket.send(request);
    } catch (SocketException e) {

        ...
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {

       ...
        }
    }
```

Other Java samples can be found [here](http://www.exampledepot.com/search/node/socket):

Comment: I've managed to connect to a server using Socket(), but i cant send any commands. Any ideas?