# send lat and long using open socket 

Tags: java, android, sockets

I want to send this Lat and Long the gps current location  on my open socket between my android and my python server .

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location loc)
{
    GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint((int) (loc.getLatitude() * 1E6),
                (int) (loc.getLongitude() * 1E6));      
    String Text = "My current location is: " +
            "Latitud =" + loc.getLatitude()+ 
            "Longitud =" +loc.getLongitude() ;
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
            Text, 
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

so i save it on string text and i add button to connect it to the server now i want to send the lat and lang each time so how to send this string  using the open socket ??

Answer (score 1):

```
String cmd("my command");
    try {
        InetSocketAddress address = new InetSocketAddress("10.1.1.1", 12350);
        DatagramPacket request = new DatagramPacket(cmd.getBytes(), cmd.length(), address);
        DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket();
        socket.send(request);
    } catch (SocketException e) {

        ...
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {

       ...
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

On the right side of the current screen I'm looking at is a section called "Related".  In that section, the first link is to [android open socket and send commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2132241)

Also, [searching on StackExchange for android sockets](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=android%20sockets) nets a good number of past questions and answers on the topic, including [Using Sockets to send and receive data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5680259).

Does this answer your question?