# Trying to set up server/client between two Android phones when one is acting as a Wifi AP and the other is connected to it

Tags: android, android-wifi

I have two phones: A and B. A is acting as a Wifi AP; B is connected to A's wifi network.
Now, I'd like for A to act as a server and B to act as a client. Here's the gist of my code:

A does the following (wrapped in its own thread and try/catch statements, of course)

```
ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(SERVERPORT);
Socket client = server.accept();
```

and then B does

```
Socket socket = new Socket(SERVERIP, SERVERPORT);
```

The SERVERIP is always the same when A activates its Wifi AP, so I've just hard coded it in for now. (I've verified this several different ways.)

When B tries to connect, I get the following exception:

```
java.net.ConnectException: /192.168.43.1:29288 - Network is unreachable
    at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:207)
    at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:183)
    at java.net.Socket.startupSocket(Socket.java:705)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:263)
    at disaster.relief.DisasterReliefActivity$ClientThread.run(DisasterReliefActivity.java:288)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
```

I tried using the same code when the two phones are on an externally created wifi network, and it works just fine. Any ideas why this wouldn't work?

**UPDATE**

I've also tried connecting to the server from my computer (when it's connected to the Wifi network) via telnet, and this works perfectly, so the problem must be when B instantiates the socket. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Can you go to the internet using this tethering via your phone connected to another? 
You should activate your server only after the tethering is UP for your network interface 
with 192.168.43.1 will be disabled before that point.
You can try and use same technique using a laptop or a pc connected with wifi to your phone 
with tethering enabled on it. you can use telnet to check if the port is available and accepting. 
You might want to read this [android open socket and send commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2132241/android-open-socket-and-send-commands).
I would also use ports in between 1024-10000. But it's up to you I guess.

---

hope it helps you abit.

Comment: In theory, yes, I can access the Internet, though the use case for which I'm building the app presumes that the cell network is unavailable (hence trying to communicate directly between the two phones). I'm already waiting until the Wifi AP is up before activating the server, so that shouldn't be the issue. Thanks for the telnet suggestion – I'm now able to connect to the server from my computer when connected to the wifi network. Any idea why I wouldn't be able to do the same from the other phone?

Comment: network is unreachable means that there could be some default routing issues or it tries to send packets using a different interface but WIFI through which it's connected. I wish I'd seen the logcat with my own eyes :(

Comment: Hey Sergey, I update the question to include the full log. Does that help by any chance?

Comment: wait. do you have a server running elsewhere? or you're running it on your phone or you want your phone A to act as a bridge to another network which has this server?

Comment: If it is the case for two different wifi networks I don't think that any android phone can act as an AP for one network while being connected to another wifi to be a BRIDGE for it.

Comment: No, I wanted the single phone to act as a wifi ap and a server. As it turns out, I think this may just not be possible. I tested my code in every other possible configuration, and it worked in all of them except this one. Ultimately I just switched which device was acting as the server and which was acting as the client (now A is the client and B is the server), and that works just fine. Thanks for your help!